# Backbone.js - Cannot read property 'Model' of undefined

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, underscore.js, backbone-model, typeerror

I've been following this tutorial: http://backbonetutorials.com/organizing-backbone-using-modules/

The error is for line 7 of home.js (Model). What am I doing wrong???

main.js

```
// js/main.js

require.config ({
    paths: {
        // Include needed files.
        jquery: '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min',
        underscore: '//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.6.0/underscore-min',
        backbone: 'libs/backbone/backbone.min'
    }
});

require([
    // Load app module and pass it
    // to the definition function.
    'app',
], function(App) {
    App.initialize();
})
```

app.js

```
// js/app.js

define ([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'backbone',
    'router' // Request router.js
], function($, _, Backbone, Router) {
    var initialize = function() {
        Router.initialize();
    }
    return {
        initialize: initialize
    };
})
```

router.js

```
// js/router.js

define ([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'backbone',
    'views/home'
], function($, _, Backbone, HomeView) {
    var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
        routes: {
            '': 'showHome'
        }
    });

    var initialize = function() {
        var app_router = new AppRouter;
        app_router.on('showHome', function() {
            var homeView = new HomeView;
            homeView.render();
        });
        Backbone.history.start();
    };

    return {
        initialize: initialize
    };
})
```

home.js (View)

```
// js/views/home.js

define ([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'backbone',
    'collections/home',
    'text!/templates/home.html' // Use Require.js text plugin to load HTML file.
], function($, _, Backbone, HomeCollection, homeTemplate) {
    var HomeView = Backbone.View.extend({
        el: $('#home'),
        initialize: function() {
            this.collection = new HomeCollection();
            this.collection.add({name: "Ginger Kid"});

            var compiledTemplate = _.template(homeTemplate, {home: this.collection.models});

            // Append our compiled template to this Views "el".
            this.$el.append(compiledTemplate);
        }
    });

    return HomeView;
})
```

home.js (Model)

```
// models/home.js

define ([
    'underscore',
    'backbone'
], function($, _, Backbone) {
    var HomeModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
        defaults: {
            name: "Bob Smith"
        }
    });

    return HomeModel;
})
```

home.js (Collection)

```
// collections/home.js

define ([
    'underscore',
    'backbone',
    'models/home'
], function($, _, Backbone, HomeModel) {
    var HomeCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model: HomeModel
    });

    return HomeCollection;
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The defines in your home collection are wrong.

```
define ([
    'underscore',
    'backbone',
    'models/home'
], function($, _, Backbone, HomeModel) {
```

Change to (you had a $ but weren't pulling in 'jquery':

```
define ([
    'backbone',
    'models/home'
], function(Backbone, HomeModel) {
```

Note that you don't need to include underscore and jQuery every time unless you are literally using them in that file (something starting with `_.` or `$.`). So you can remove those underscore and jquery defines in the other files too until you actually use them. See my note below on ensuring load order.

Your model.js has the same problem:

```
define ([
    'underscore',
    'backbone'
], function($, _, Backbone) {
```

Change to (you had a $ but weren't pulling in 'jquery':

```
define ([
    'backbone'
], function(Backbone) {
```

Add this to your require config in `main.js` because it ensures that jquery and underscore are loaded first by saying they are a dependency of Backbone.

```
shim: {
    backbone: {
        deps: [
            'underscore',
            'jquery'
        ],
        exports: 'Backbone'
    }
}
```

Comment: Should "shim", "deps" and "exports" have double quotes? I saw this shim example somewhere else and only backbone had double quotes?

Comment: Actually I use single quotes for everything except json files I recommend you convert to single for consistency though it makes no difference

Comment: I mean that the example I saw had no quotes on shim, deps, and exports; except on 'backbone'.

Comment: Ah yeah feel free to not put in quotes everything apart from 'underscore', 'jquery' and 'Backbone' - the other things are keys so they are assumed to be strings - you only need to put those in strings if they have a hyphen `-` in them

Comment: Perfect, I can now render the blank page with no errors. Many thanks!